# Monthly Schedule in Azure data factory pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

How can we schedule a Azure Data Factory pipeline to run only on particular day of month.(for e.g 9th of every month)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the "schedule trigger" capability in the V2 ADF service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers#examples-recurrence-schedules

Answer (score 0):

If you are using data factory version 1, you can achieve this by setting the availability with frequency month, interval 1, and set the offset with the number of the day you want the pipeline to run.

For example if you want it to run the 9th of each month as you said, you will have something like this:

```
 "availability": {
"frequency": "Month",
"interval": 1,
"offset": "9.00:00:00", 
"style": "StartOfInterval"
}
```

If you are using data factory version 2, this can be achieved with triggers as Mark Kromer said. You have to set {monthDays":[9]} in the trigger's schedule.

Cheers.